# Simple calculus question about an equation involving gradient.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

the equation I'm dealing with is motivated by physics, but my problem is purely mathematical, so I think this is a good place to ask. The equation is the following

$$
\nabla h =\frac{\nabla P}{\rho}
$$

where $h$, $P$ and $\rho$ are differentiable scalar functions, and $\nabla$ denotes the gradient operator.

I know that:

$\rho$ is a function of spatial coordinates, $\rho=\rho(x,y,z)$.

The function $P$ depends only on $\rho$, $P=P(\rho)$.

I need to show that $h$ depends only on $P$, $h=h(P)$, with this information and the equation with gradients above. How could I do that?

I guess it should be an easy task taking into account the geometrical interpretation of a gradient, but I have forgotten so many things from my calculus course...

Comment: Is it about thermodynams?

Comment: By taking integral of a gradient from state $1$ to state $2$ you can show both $h$ explicitly and also $h=h(P)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar Yes, h represents specific enthalpy, p is the pressure and rho is the density. But I don't understand how to use that theorem. If I integrate at each side, what happends to grad P/rho ?

Comment: If you integrate from a gradient, the gradient will exclude so that: $\Delta h \to h$ by using gradient theorem.